# Why is this not a category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, order-theory

[image]

Why need the composite of two monotone functions not be monotone?

This is from *Rings and Categories of Modules*, Anderson and Fuller, page 7.

Comment: It's not the only error. On page 7 the authors claim that in concrete categories isomorphisms coincide with bijective morphisms. And the definition of a category on page 6 is awkward since the identities don't belong to the data (which they should), and the identities are required to be unique (which is automatic). It also strikes me as hell that the authors *support* on page 7 the common error of ignoring forgetful functors: "It is a common practice in algebra to identify an object in a category with its underlying set."

Comment: It depends on whether "monotone" means "strictly monotone" or "weakly monotone," I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the claim is false: composition of monotone functions is monotone.

Clearly the composite of two order preserving maps is again an order preserving map.
If $f \colon P \to Q$ is an monotone increasing map and $g \colon Q \to R$ is a monotone decreasing it is easy to see that 
$$x \leq y \Rightarrow f(x) \leq f(y) \Rightarrow g(f(x)) \geq g(f(y))$$
and so $g \circ f$ is a reverse order map.
Similarly for $f \colon P \to Q$ monotone decreasing and $g \colon Q \to R$ increasing.
Finally in the case where both $f \colon P \to Q$ and $g \colon Q \to R$ are monotone decreasing we have that 
$$x \leq y \Rightarrow f(x) \geq f(y) \Rightarrow g(f(x)) \leq g(f(y))$$
hence $g\circ f$ is monotone increasing.

Comment: your first formula has typos, you may wish to correct it

Comment: Indeed the claim is false. Does this category of monotone functions have a standard name?

Comment: I doubt it, and it is kind of weird of including both types of monotone functions.

Comment: A little add: if instead one consider the families $mor_{\mathbb P}(O,Q)$ of decreasing monotone functions these data do not form a category.... well not in the natural way.